# Control strategy for upper/lower limit control

Tags: control-engineering

I am currently facing a problem, for which I cannot find a decent control strategy. The problem is that I want to limit an observable/measurable variable in its maximum and minimum.

As an example I would choose a car's speed. With the throttle, I can control the torque and the speed is measurable. The target is to control the vehicle's speed to not surpass a specific maximum value.

What I am searching for:

[image]

Control would already start above the red line and smoothly let the car reach its desired speed. But, the system should be able to stay right below the upper threshold with no controller intervention.

Using a plain PID did not succeed, there were too many issues (control would only take affect when the value was greater than the desired value; I would need to calculate a "target" value; looking ahead, taking the acceleration into account; lowering the upper threshold for the P-Part and so on).

I assume, that I need to take the systems dynamics into account. Otherwise one would not be able to predict whether the maximum will be exceeded or not.

From what I understood, using trajectory planning with constraints is one approach to do so. But for that, I would need to know the complete system dynamics, e.g. for my vehicle drag, mass, rolling resistance and so on.

Therefore I would like to know, if you know any control methods/approaches that could help me to solve my problem. Maybe even without knowing the exact system dynamics.

Comment: See if my answer to [Understanding the flow of a PI Controller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/346759/73158) helps. "*PID ... control would only take effect when the value is greater than the desired value*" is not correct. The P controller would start to reduce as soon as you get into the proportional band (above the red line in your diagram).

Comment: It might worth checking out model predictive control.